# Python SQLite Query Returning Partial Results

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm very new to Python, just trying to get my feet wet.  Any and all help is appreciated.

When I run the BlueToys portion of this code, with the limit 10 included, I get the appropriate results of ten results matching the Color = 'blue' specification.  However, when trying to select the BlueBike portion, that is, for each of the ten results in BlueToys, return 25 results, I end up with unexpected output.  If I print BlueToys I get the ten results I would expect.  If I print BlueBike I get one set of 25, that is 25 matches to one item from BlueToys.  Is there a looping part of this that I'm missing?

```
import math, time
import json, urllib
import sqlite3, csv

myConnection = sqlite3.connect('Collection.db')
myCursor = myConnection.cursor()

sqlstring = """
select Item from ToyStore where Color = 'blue' order by random() limit 10"""

BlueToys = myCursor.execute(sqlstring).fetchall()
for Toy in BlueToys:
    sqlstring = """select * from Manufacturer where Bike = %s order by random() limit 25""" % (Toy)
    BlueBike = myCursor.execute(sqlstring).fetchall()

print BlueToys
print BlueBike
```

Comment: Your `print BlueBike` line is outside the loop. Move it inside the `for` loop by indenting.

Comment: @Selcuk exactly what I needed, thanks a million.